# How to display no text on radiobutton but has a value c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

Anyone know who to display NO text in a radiobutton item but have a value for each?

Here is my radio button list:

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoD4_1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="407px">
                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Problem is that it displays 0,1,2 etc next to each list item - I want to keep the value but show no text - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the Value and Text attributes.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```